# Click on Image to follow Link (JSON Custom Formatting)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I'm trying to set up custom JSON formatting with an image that is clickable to follow a link. I can display the image OK (using "elmType": "img"), and I can set up text that links OK (using "elmType": "a"), but I can't seem to combine the two.

The following code I think shows my intent, but does not create the link, rather it only displays the image:

```
{
  "elmType": "img",
  "style": {
    "display": "block",
    "background-color": "#abeccd",
    "position": "relative",
    "width": "225px",
    "height": "225px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "src": "[$ImageLink]",
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "http://www.google.co.uk"
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to nest two elements in JSON to create clickable image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to nest two elements (`img` element inside `a` element) in JSON to create clickable image.

**Example**:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "[$RedirectLink]"
  },
  "style": {
    "text-decoration": "none"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "img",
      "style": {
        "display": "block",
        "background-color": "#abeccd",
        "position": "relative",
        "width": "50px",
        "height": "50px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "src": "[$ImageLink]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. In fact I used the same principle to turn the entire div, including the image, into link (this is what I needed ideally).